# Is there a verbose mode of SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe?

Tags: c++, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I have some problems while scanning a mixed C#, C++ solution with `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe`. (during the `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe` end) So I want to ask if there is a verbose option to activate enhanced/debug output.

The output is that a file is not found, but there is a additional subfolder in the path that is not correct, and I want to understand where it comes from.

Example: `a.cpp` is located on `C:\src\ProjektA\Modul1`, but the output says:

```
"Warn: Cannot find the file "C:\src\ProjektA\**Modul2**\Module1\a.cpp" skipping violations"
```

By the way: in `FilesToAnalyse.txt` the path is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To activate verbose mode, you simply need to pass the following argument:

```
/d:sonar.verbose=true
```

Reference: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Additional+Analysis+Parameters

Comment: This is a valid answer, but for C# that argument should be passed to the SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin ... command and it will take effect for the end command too.